# Asp.NET add hiddenfield with runat server from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls, runatserver

I want to dynamically create a HiddenField in C#, I'm able to do that, but I don't know how to add runat="server".

```
HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
hf.ID = "hf";
hf.Value = "0";
// hf.runat = server; ???
```

Comment: The `runat=server` is added when add to HiddenField in any control for example: `Panel1.Controls.Add(hf)`

Comment: To Display Data
Refer This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526713/creating-a-hidden-field-in-codebehind-and-accessing-it-via-clientside-javascript)